# Parallel.For loop for spell checking using NHunspell and c#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, nhunspell

I have a list of string and if I run spell checking using NHunspell in sequential manner then everything works fine; but if I use Parallel.For loop against the List the application stops working in the middle( some address violation error )

```
public static bool IsSpellingRight(string inputword, byte[] frDic, byte[] frAff, byte[] enDic, byte[] enAff)
{
    if (inputword.Length != 0)
    {
        bool correct;
        if (IsEnglish(inputword))
        {
            using (var hunspell = new Hunspell(enAff, enDic))
            {
                correct = hunspell.Spell(inputword);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var hunspell = new Hunspell(frAff, frDic))
            {
                correct = hunspell.Spell(inputword);
            }
        }
        return correct ;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

var poptions = new ParallelOptions();

// Keep one core/CPU free...
poptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
{
    Parallel.For(0, total, poptions, i =>
    {
        if (words[i] != "")
        {
            _totalWords++;

            if (IsSpellingRight(words[i],dictFileBytes,
                affFileBytes,dictFileBytesE,affFileBytesE))
            {
                // do something   

            }
            else
            {
                BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
                {
                    //do something on UI thread
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}, tokenSource.Token);

task.ContinueWith((t) => BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
{
    MessaageBox.Show("Done");
})));
```

Comment: Where's the list and the loop you're talking about? It's more possible, that you just mess something up when using list from multiple threads.

Comment: The list nothing but a tokenized list of words built from the text of a RichTextBox

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Hunspell class, but you could just type `correct = true;` or `false`, run it and then just see whether the problem lies within your method or your Parallel.For loop. There is nothing I could see wrong in the code you've pasted, unless Hunspell is a singleton - then it would obviously mean you can't use it this way.

Comment: Inside my Parallel.For loop where I run the above spell checking method, if I replace it with If(true) then there is no error. The problem lies in the spell checking method running in parallel

Comment: Last attempt: check if `bool IsEnglish(string)` a thread-safe method by just changing it to true or false. Have no other ideas.

Comment: You are probably right, setting it as true or false raises no exception. So what should I do?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain exactly how to lock your method.

Comment: Could you post the full exception you're getting, including stack trace?

Comment: What is the implementation of the `IsEnglish` method?

Comment: Trying to "keep one CPU free" is pointless. The TPL takes care to use as many threads as needed (threads, NOT CPUs). It will even increase/reduce the number of threads depending on the execution time of previous iterations. Additionally, using BeginInvoke is unnecessary, use SyncrhonizationContext.Post instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you should forget about your parallel loop implement the things right.**

Are you aware of the fact that this code loads and constructs the dictionary:

```
    using (var hunspell = new Hunspell(enAff, enDic))
    {
        correct = hunspell.Spell(inputword);
    }
```

Your are loading and construction the dictionary over and over again with your code. This is awfully slow! Load Your dictionary once and check all words, then dispose it. And don't do this in parallel because Hunspell objects are not thread safe.

**Pseodocode:**

```
Hunspell hunspell = null;
try
{
    hunspell = new Hunspell(enAff, enDic)

    for( ... )
    {
      hunspell.Spell(inputword[i]);
    }
    }
}
finally
{
    if( hunspell != null ) hunspell.Dispose();
}
```

If you need to check words massive in parallel consider to read this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43769/Spell-Check-Hyphenation-and-Thesaurus-for-NET-with

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I can see a potential problem. In line

```
_totalWords++;
```

you're incrementing a value, that (I suppose) is declared somewhere outside the loop. Use locking mechanism.

edit:
Also, you could use `Interlocked.Increment(ref val);`, which would be faster, than simple locking.

edit2:
Here's how the locking I described in comment should look like for the problem you encounter:

```
static object Locker = new object();    //anywhere in the class

//then in your method
if (inputword.Length != 0)
{
   bool correct;
   bool isEnglish;
   lock(Locker) {isEnglish = IsEnglish(inputword);}
   if(isEnglish)
   {
       //..do your stuff
   }
    //rest of your function
}
```

Comment: I removed it, still same problem. only if I set true or false in bool IsEnglish(string) the program runs fine. So what should I do now?

Comment: I think the problem might be in the variable 'correct' which more than one thread tries to change. Am I right, because I followed your instruction to lock IsEnglish method but same problem

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the locking object only once? That's important for locking it on the same reference. If so, I'm sorry but I can't help you. There are many possibilities. The only way I see is to mess with the values returned. Set the method to always return true, false, force `else` statement to be true and so on.

Comment: Ok I will follow your instruction and revert. Anyway thanks for helping me out

Comment: I have removed 'correct' variable( commented out correct = hunspell.Spell(inputword); lines). But strangely same error. So I think there is something in the NHunspell library, because Visual Studio debug window is also pointing to NHunspell

Comment: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt error comes up in the line:-      using (var hunspell = new Hunspell(asAff, asDic))

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in NHunspell.dll       ----- thatz the error message in debug output window